# Laravel 5 back() working on dev server, but not production

Tags: php, laravel-5, back

We have a site developed in `Laravel 5.8`.

When we move the code to the production server, our `back()` function references all result in a `302` redirect to the home page.

On development, they redirect properly. We've been trying to find a point of differentiation between the servers and the PHP versions are the only significant differentiator. Development is running `7.3.11` and production is `7.2.26`.

We're having the production server updated to match, but both of these versions are ahead of `v7.1.3` required by Laravel.

Does it seem like the PHP version is the issue or are we missing something else?

Comment: can you share a sample  of your code, please?

Comment: Try to echo ```URL::previous();``` or ```$request->header('referer');``` to check the page that sent the request. If it's a 404 page, the redirect go to homepage.

Comment: relative / absolute URLs? Does your dev site run in some subdirectory?

Comment: Can you post the URL? Which browsers have you tested? Does the session work? Laravel stores the last page in the session and uses that if there is no `Referer` HTTP header.